# Why can't I connect to my launchpad ppa with quickly?

Tags: ppa, launchpad, quickly

Can anyone make sence of the following output:

```
confus@confus:~/prog/power-switch$ quickli configure ppa
confus@confus:~/prog/power-switch$ quickly configure ppa Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/configure.py", line 66, in <module>
    templatetools.handle_additional_parameters(sys.argv, help, shell_completion, usage=usage)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quickly/templatetools.py", line 51, in handle_additional_parameters
    shell_completion(args[2:])
  File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/configure.py", line 61, in shell_completion
    rv = packaging.shell_complete_ppa(argv[-1])
  File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/internal/packaging.py", line 302, in shell_complete_ppa
    launchpad = launchpadaccess.initialize_lpi(False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quickly/launchpadaccess.py", line 91, in initialize_lpi
    allow_access_levels=["WRITE_PRIVATE"])
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 538, in login_with
    credential_save_failed, version)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 341, in _authorize_token_and_login
    authorization_engine.unique_consumer_id)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/launchpadlib/credentials.py", line 273, in load
    return self.do_load(unique_key)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/launchpadlib/credentials.py", line 322, in do_load
    return Credentials.from_string(credential_string)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/launchpadlib/credentials.py", line 89, in from_string
    credentials.load(StringIO(value))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/authorize/oauth.py", line 165, in load
    CREDENTIALS_FILE_VERSION, 'consumer_key')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 610, in get
    raise NoOptionError(option, section)
ConfigParser.NoOptionError: No option 'consumer_key' in section: '1'
None
confus@confus:~/prog/power-switch$ quickli configure ppa None
```

Corresponding bug-report on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpadlib/+bug/793174

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm getting same error when trying to `quickly release`.

Comment: Any updates on this? :)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Comment: Seems like nobody care about the problem. Feel free to add a comment on your specific problem at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpadlib/+bug/793174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Quickly. You should report this bug on Launchpad using the command:

`ubuntu-bug quickly`

and attach the output from the command.

Comment: Yeah, I already did half an hour ago. Just asked because AU is normally faster than launchpad x-D
Also I suspect it's rather an error in liblaunchbad-integration or its python version.